# ajax form submission refreshes page

Tags: javascript, ajax, razor

I'm working on this project and am attempting to make a call to a controller function without performing a page refresh. I tried setting up an ajax function in order to do this but haven't had any luck. I've placed the related script both in the html and in a separate jquery.js but to no avail. It appears as if the form submission just isn't hitting the script at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated!! The form is in a cshtml file, controller in .cs, and script in .js

the form in question:

```
<form id="tableForm"  action="@(Url.Action("AddToOrder", "Order"))" method="post">
                                    @{foreach (var item in (IList<Item>)ViewData["items"]){
                                    <input type="hidden" id="@("item_id_" + item.id)" name="@("item_id_" + item.id)" value="@item.id" />
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>@item.description</td>
                                        <td>@String.Format("{0:C}",item.price)</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" id="@("item_quantity_" + @item.id)" name="@("item_quantity_" + @item.id)" style="width: 50px;" value="0" /></td>
                                     </tr>
                                      }}
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Add item(s) to order" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </form>
```

the script in question:

```
$('#tableForm').submit(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        succes: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

To reiterate, the controller and method are working great, but the form submission refreshes the page.

Comment: Are you sure your submit handler is called? Does the alert display?

Comment: Please show your complete page source. A failure of any Javascript will cause the handler to not run at all, which will leave the normal submit behavior in place. You may just be missing a library include or have placed your JavaScript in the `head` element without a DOM ready handler.

Answer (score 0):

refer the below code, call the preventdetfault after the submission

```
$('#tableForm').submit(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        succes: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: That won't make any difference. You can call `.preventDefault()` from anywhere within the submit handler to stop the default submission.

Answer (score 0):

Is your AJAX method getting called on page submission. Try adding an alert to confirm that.
You might want to add ClientIdMOde="static" to your form tag, so that if it is with in master page the control id will be static and JS can bind to it.

May be clientidmode will do the trick.
Let me know if it doesn't

Comment: All good suggestions (except `clientidmode` as it is not `runat="server"`), but best left as comments. This is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without your full page shown, I can only make an educated guess: that you have included your `.js` file *at the top of the page or in the `head` element*.

That means that the following code does nothing (returns an empty jQuery object):

```
$('#tableForm')
```

That is because the code runs as soon as it is loaded/defined and the `form` element it references has not been loaded yet.

The simply solution is: to either put your JS code at the end of the `body` element, or wrap it in a DOM-ready event handler. The handler is preferred as you can be moved about the page without failing:

e.g.

```
$(function(){
   // your jQuery code here can now use the DOM safely
});
```

which is a shortcut for this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // your jQuery code here can now use the DOM safely
});
```

That means you code will now look like:

```
$(function(){
    $('#tableForm').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            succes: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

*If it still fails, the usual cause in a Javascript error preceding your code (missing jQuery library include etc). You will need to show your entire page to clarify that though.*